# Which version of Ubuntu should I use on an old MAcbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, versions

I have an old Macbook Pro 15 Inch from 2009. It has 
Memory 3.7 G
Processor Intel® Core™ i7 CPU M 620 @ 2.67GHz × 4 
Graphics NVA5
Gnome 3.28.2
OS 64 bit
Disk 491 GB

I am running Ubuntu  18.04.3 LTS - it struggles to start up often requiring multiple attempts to start and does not allow me to create documents or save files. I have had to reload GRUB and added in a boot-repair tool (tutorial here https://www.techradar.com/uk/how-to/computing/how-to-boot-repair-ubuntu-1315203). This enabled me to reboot normally but it still takes a long time and sometimes requires two tries.

I wonder if my old computer would run better with a different version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Your hardware is good for any Ubuntu release. But if it has hardware problems, changing the release won't improve things.

Comment: Why don't you try for yourself and see - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0   It applies too for flavors, and which flavor suits you is a personal thing (yes GNOME the default is on the heavy end of the scale, but personal preferences play a large part on which is *best*).  Spec wise your machine is good (though didn't see RAM which I think most important) but the wrong changes to a OS can ruin it..

Comment: It sounds like a hardware issue. Check your disk health.

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu. It's based on Debian and Ubuntu, but it's much faster and reliable. https://xubuntu.org/requirements/